# Export hardware specifications to a spreadsheet for Windows Server

Tags: scripting, powershell, windows, vbscript

I have a bunch of servers : Windows 2003 and 2008. I just wanted to export these hardware specs to a spreadsheet:

cpus : num processors, clock speed, etc

total hard disk space

total used disk space

computer model

I started writing a script to do this via diskpart, systeminfo, and wmic. But before I get too crazy and reinvent the wheel, just wondering if someone knows of a powershell, vb script, or something else that could do this.

Comment: something like this? - http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/computermanagement/hardware/ OR http://www.powershellpro.com/wp-content/uploads/CompInv_v2.ps1

Comment: Thanks. These both look very nice. I will have to play with them.

Comment: @ColdT that worked pretty good. I had to fiddle with the firewall for the PCs a bit but I was able to do nice pivot tables with the data. Did you want to put your links as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options via VBS or PS, can be easily found of the net.

http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/

http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-forum/hardware/computer-inventory-script/